# Using filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a filter with an expression in ng-repeat like this -

```
<div ng-repeat= "fruit in fruits | filter: {fruit.color !: 'red'}">
   {{ fruit }}
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, can someone confirm that it is possible to use expression in filters(I am using angular 1.0.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should upgrade you Angular Version to latest, it would not make sense to stay with Angular 1.0.x

```
<div ng-repeat= "fruit in fruits | filter: {color : '!' + selected Color}">
   {{ fruit }}
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm, In my case I have used it as a variable                                                                                                     `<div ng-repeat= "fruit in fruits | filter: {color : '!' + colorToleave}">
   {{ fruit }}
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is just example of filter in ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat= "fruit in fruits" >
     {{ fruit | uppercase}} 
</div>

$scope.fruits  = ['apple','banana']
```

OutPut:

```
APPLE
BANANA
```